# Split a string just before each occurrence of 3 specific delimiters

Tags: php, regex, split, delimiter, preg-split

I'm a bit lost with `preg_split()` in parsing a string with multiple delimiters and keeping the delimiter in the 'after' part of the split.

My delimiters are `$`, `#`, and `?`.

For instance:

```
$str = 'participant-$id#-group';
$ar = preg_split('/([^$#?]+[$#?]+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo "<pre>";  print_r( $ar); echo "</pre>";
```

will show:

```
Array
(
    [0] => participant_data-$
    [1] => id#
    [2] => -group
)
```

However I need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => participant_data-
    [1] => $id
    [2] => #-group
)
```

Regex makes my brain hurt. so could someone advise how I use `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` and keep the delimiter at the beginning of the segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$ar = preg_split('/(\$[^#]+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: @user2968159 I assume that the `$id` is begin with `$` and doesn't contains `#`, so the regular expression `(\$[^#]+)` is consists of `\$` and `[^#]+`.

Comment: @user2968159 And it will returns delimiter pattern because the flag `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` has been set. For another example, it will returns `['participant-', '$id', '#-group-', '$id2']` for the input `participant-$id#-group-$id2`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I think i get that

Comment: The explanation belongs in the body of the answer, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

How about this. I am capturing the delimiters and then put them back together.

```
<?php

$str = 'participant-$id#-group';
$ar = preg_split('/([^$#?]+[^$#?]+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo "<pre>";  print_r( $ar); echo "</pre>";  

/*
Array
(
    [0] => participant-
    [1] => $
    [2] => id
    [3] => #
    [4] => -group
) */

$result = array();
$result[] = $ar[0];
for($i=1;$i<count($ar);$i+=2) {
    $result[] = $ar[$i] . $ar[$i+1];
}

echo "<pre>";  print_r( $result); echo "</pre>";  

/*
Array
(
    [0] => participant-
    [1] => $id
    [2] => #-group
)
*/

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to capture the delimiters, just use a lookahead for the `$`, `#`, or `?`.  This will split your string on the zero-width position before the delimiters.  No characters will be lost/consumed why exploding.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rq6KL))

```
$str = 'participant-$id#-group';

var_export(
    preg_split('/(?=[$#?])/', $str)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'participant-',
  1 => '$id',
  2 => '#-group',
)
```